# How to decrease a shape of numpy.ndarray?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have R <class 'numpy.ndarray'> of shape (30,30,30). How to get the shape (30,30,29), please?

```
R[:-1]
```

gives (29,30,30)

```
R[::-1]
```

gives again (30,30,30), why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify all axis that the array has. Do something like:

```
R[:,:,:-1]
```

The explation for it is: take all the items in the first axis, also take all for the second, and take all but the last one for the 3rd axis.
The reason why your two options are wrong are:

- The first one just refers to the first axis.
- The second one, if you put : two times, it is referring to [start:stop:step]. By omitting start and stop it assumes the full lenght of the array. By putting -1 to the step, it reverses the order of the array, but again only in the first axis.